# How to read file and store it into json array in Android studio

Tags: java, android, json

Here is code in Android Studio in that I am creating a json object with username and password of one user and storing it to json array (just to have more users). In fact a am converting it to String before storing. 
So How can I read and store it back to json array that contains my json object?

Here is code

```
public void storeJson() {

            jobj = new JSONObject();

            try {
                jobj.put("username",usern);
                jobj.put("password",passwd);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            jarray = new JSONArray();
            jarray.put(jobj);
            String str = jarray.toString();

            try {
                fileOutputStream =  openFileOutput(passwordFile, 0);
                fileWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);

                try {
                    fileWriter.write(str);
                    fileWriter.flush();
                    fileWriter.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Written", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    username.setText("");
                    password.setText("");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Write Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

}

Comment: try this 
`new Gson().fromJson(response, new TypeToken<YourObject>() {
                            }.getType())`
with this code you can convert string json to your object

Comment: I am a beginner in this sphere and don't get it clearly. But there is no Gson library builtin. and I have String variable read from file. And I need to convert it back to json as it was initially.

Comment: I guess i managed this. All I needed was to write:::                                   jarray = new JSONArray(temp_pwd);

                        int len = jarray.length();
                        jobj = new JSONObject();
                        jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(0);
                        String strr = jobj.getString("username");
                        String sstr = jobj.getString("password");